# Global Exception Handling in asp.net webforms

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, visual-studio, webforms

I have an existing project, it is in asp.net web forms

in that project every event (page_load,button_click,dropdown_selectionIndexChanged etc.....) is calling in between try catch block like below

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        checkLogin();
        //some logic
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        ShowMessage(ex.Message + "<br />" + ex.StackTrace, 1);
    }
}
```

in existing project we are just showing exception message to the users.

Now i want to log all exception messages in a log file( i can able to write log files)

but in my project we have many number of web pages and every page having many events, so for logging each and every catch block in all events is to much time consuming and i need to write the log code in all catch blocks in all pages.

so is there any option to globally write log message for all try catch events in all pages.

it would be more helpful to me

Thanks,

Comment: There is a place where you can catch all exception at the application level, i.e. `Application_Error` event handler in `Global.asax` where you can apply the logging function, But as you described, the exceptions actually captured at the page level individually, which means you'll still have to log exceptions page by page.

Comment: Seems to me you just need to modify `ShowMessage()` so that it writes stuff to a log and then shows a more generic error message or redirects to a general error page.

Answer (score 0):

You can capture unhanded (and thread) exceptions using the Application.ThreadException and AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException properties.
Your Main method would be look as below:

```
[STAThread]
static void Main() { 

    if (Debugger.IsAttached) {
        Run();
        return;
    } 

    Application.ThreadException += ApplicationThreadException;
    AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += CurrentDomainUnhandledException;
    Run();
}
```

Note the debugger check, just so the debugger can catch these exceptions.
The Run function is pretty simple

```
static void Run() {
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

And then the two exception handlers.
Generally it is not a bad idea to do something meaningful during this events - logging the exceptions (or sending them to admin) and displaying a message to users.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.dispatcherunhandledexception.aspx

```
static void ApplicationThreadException(object sender, ThreadExceptionEventArgs e) {
    ErrorInformationDialog eid = new ErrorInformationDialog(e.Exception.Message, e.Exception);
    eid.ShowDialog();
}

static void CurrentDomainUnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e) {
    ErrorInformationDialog eid = new ErrorInformationDialog(e.ExceptionObject as Exception);
    eid.ShowDialog();
}
```